# Generic struct that accepts box-clonable trait objects

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I want to create a generic struct with type `T` that accepts all `T` that implement the `Base` trait, and `Box<T>` is `Clone`. I am running into the following issue:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:38:12
   |
38 |     inner: InnerStore<T>,
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `T`
   |
note: required by a bound in `InnerStore`
  --> src/main.rs:33:22
   |
33 | struct InnerStore<T: Clone> {
   |                      ^^^^^ required by this bound in `InnerStore`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
37 | struct BaseStore<T: Base + ?Sized + std::clone::Clone> {
   |                                   +++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

This is a minimal example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
// Two traits: A Base and Extension
trait Base {
    fn do_something(&self) -> u32;
    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Base>;
}


trait Extension: Base {
    fn do_something_else(&self) -> u32;
}


// The Base implements Clone for Box<dyn Base>
impl Clone for Box<dyn Base> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.box_clone()
    }
}

// An implementation of Extension
struct Implementation {}

impl Base for Implementation {
    fn do_something(&self) -> u32 {
        1
    }

    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Base> {
        Box::new(Implementation {})
    }
}

impl Extension for Implementation {
    fn do_something_else(&self) -> u32 {
        2
    }
}


// Two generic nested structs with type T
// BaseStore<T> holds an InnerStore<Box<T>>
// InnerStore<T> requires T (i.e., Box<T> from BaseStore) to be Clone
struct InnerStore<T: Clone> {
    item: T,
}

struct BaseStore<T: Base + ?Sized> {
    inner: InnerStore<Box<T>>,
}


impl<T> BaseStore<T>
where
    T: Base + ?Sized,
{
    fn new(item: Box<T>) -> BaseStore<T> {
        BaseStore {
            inner: InnerStore { item },
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let store: BaseStore<dyn Extension> = BaseStore::new(Box::new(Implementation {}));
}
```

This seems to come down to the fact that the `Clone` implementation for `Box<dyn Base>` is not inherited for `Box<dyn Extension>`. How could I achieve this behaviour, and tell `BaseStore` that `Box<T>` must be `Clone`, without requiring `T` itself to be `Clone`?

Comment: You might be thinking too much in terms of inheritance here, which is something Rust tends to avoid. As such, the path is cluttered with obstacles. Extending traits like that might seem normal if coming from, say, C++, but within Rust it's actually less about inheritance and more about dependencies. You'll often see `trait X : Y` meaning trait `X` depends on features `Y` offers, where those are usually low-level like `Clone` or `Sync`, not something that adds base-class functionality.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? There's likely a more idiomatic Rust approach to getting to where you want to go.

Comment: @tadman That's an interesting point you make regarding inheritance. I am indeed still quite new to Rust. What I am trying to achieve is a bit hard to explain, but let me try. I'm looking for a way to have a generic struct `BaseStore<T>` that can hold any type `T` that implements certain base functionality (`trait Base`). However, `T` should not be restricted to `dyn Base`, and it must should also be `Clone`. For example, it should be able to hold `Box<dyn Base>`, `Box<dyn Extension>`, and `Implementation` in the example above.

Comment: `Box<T> where T: Base` is **not** the same as `Box<dyn Base>`! The compiler will not consider your `impl Clone for Box<dyn Base>`, because it is not valid vor all `Box<T> where T: Base`! You sadly can't `impl<T> Clone for Box<T> where T: Base` because at least one of the two sides of an impl has to local to the current crate.

Comment: Rust can be a bit tricky to work with at times because it often requires inverting your expectations. That's a strategy you're trying to implement, but I'm curious about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: What's the point of `BaseStore<T: Base + ?Sized>`? Be aware that during compilation, this has to be resolved to a **single** type. Meaning, it will only be able to hold this one type. A generic is not a wildcard, it is a placeholder that has to be filled during compilation. There is no simple way of storing multiple items in the same data structure and recover their previous types afterwards. Rust has (almost) zero dynamic typing, Rust is one of the most statically typed languages that exist. All of this makes me think this entire question is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Yes, the more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that you have a basic misunderstanding of how generics work. *"I want to create a generic `struct` with type `T` that accepts all `T` that implement the `Base` trait, and `Box<T>` is `Clone`"* - this makes no sense. A `T` always resolves to a specific type, so the correct sentence would be *"A `struct` with a generic type `T` whose objects accept **a specific** `T` that implements the `Base` trait, and `Box<T>` is `Clone`"*. That would be achievable with generics, the original sentence is not.

Comment: @Finomnis `Box` is `#[fundamental]`, so this is possible.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Wow! This is the first time I've heard of `#[fundamental]`. I'll delete the message you are referring to. But it doesn't invalidate the other messages and the feeling that this is an XY problem.